# Two heatmaps with unified colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I have 2 heatmaps sharing the same colorbar in between.
I would like to edit the number of colors, and have in the colorbar some additional ticks without numbers - so that there will be a tick between every 2 different colors.

I saw solutions, such as using `samples = ...`, or `zmajorticks = false`, or `ztick = \empty`.

However, none of them works. Maybe it's because I don't have the `\axis` command, and don't know where to locate it, as I have `groupplot`.

Below is a MWE. 
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
    \pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
    \pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{groupplot}[
          group style = {
            group size = 2 by 1,
            horizontal sep = 4cm,
          },
          view = {0}{90},
          /pgfplots/colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(1);gray(1cm)=(0)},
          samples = 2,
        ]

          \nextgroupplot[
               xtick = {0, 0.005, 0.01},
               ytick = {0, 0.005, 0.01},
               xticklabels ={0, 0.005, 0.01},
               yticklabels ={0, 0.005, 0.01},
                colorbar left,
                colorbar style = {
                    samples = 2,
                    at={(rel axis cs: 1.3,0)},
                    anchor=south,
                    width=2mm,
                    view={0}{90},
                    zticklabels={0.5,0.55, 0.6, 0.65},
                }
                ]
                    \addplot3[
                        samples = 2,
                        surf,
                        shader=faceted,
                        point meta min=0.5,point meta max=0.66,
                    ]
      table[header=false] {
    0.0000 0.0000 0.5038
    0.0050 0.0000 0.5538
    0.0100 0.0000 0.6034
    0.0150 0.0000 0.6066

    0.0000 0.0050 0.5135
    0.0050 0.0050 0.5635
    0.0100 0.0050 0.6132
    0.0150 0.0050 0.6159

    0.0000 0.0100 0.5233
    0.0050 0.0100 0.5733
    0.0100 0.0100 0.6231
    0.0150 0.0100 0.6253

    0.0000 0.0150 0.5243
    0.0050 0.0150 0.5745
    0.0100 0.0150 0.6243
    0.0150 0.0150 0.6262

        };
          \nextgroupplot[
               xmin=0, xmax=0.015,
               ymin=0, ymax=0.015,
               xtick = {0, 0.005, 0.01},
               ytick = {0, 0.005, 0.01},
               xticklabels ={0, 0.005, 0.01},
               yticklabels ={0, 0.005, 0.01},
                 colorbar style = {
                    samples = 2,
                    at={(rel axis cs: 1.3,0)},
                    anchor=south,
                    width=2mm,
                  view={0}{90},
                 }
                ]
      \addplot3[
      surf,
      shader=faceted,
        point meta min=0.5,point meta max=0.72,
                samples = 2
      ]
      table[header=false] {
    0.0000 0.0000 0.5138
    0.0050 0.0000 0.5738
    0.0100 0.0000 0.6334
    0.0150 0.0000 0.6666

    0.0000 0.0050 0.5135
    0.0050 0.0050 0.5835
    0.0100 0.0050 0.6332
    0.0150 0.0050 0.6459

    0.0000 0.0100 0.5433
    0.0050 0.0100 0.5933
    0.0100 0.0100 0.6431
    0.0150 0.0100 0.6653

    0.0000 0.0150 0.5543
    0.0050 0.0150 0.5745
    0.0100 0.0150 0.6443
    0.0150 0.0150 0.6762
        };
      \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 2):

Did you have something like that in mind? [image: code below]

For the not-so-minimal working example (next time, please try to focus on the main problem), i put some of your settings in the overall groupplot command. However, what was missing in your code were simply the "colorbar sampled" and "point meta min/max" commands. BTW you need only one bar for your approach - so no reason for the second one.

**Update #1:** extended version as an answer to first question

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
    \pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
    group style = {
        group size = 2 by 1,
        horizontal sep = 4cm,
    },
    samples = 2,
    view = {0}{90},
    xtick = {0, 0.005, 0.01},
    xticklabels ={0, 0.005, 0.01},
    yticklabels ={0, 0.005, 0.01},
    ytick = {0, 0.005, 0.01},
    /pgfplots/colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(1);gray(1cm)=(0)},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[
    colorbar left,
    colorbar sampled, % essential command
    colorbar style = {
        samples = 7,  % gives 6 color fields within the bar
        at={(rel axis cs: 1.3,0)},
        anchor=south,
        width=2mm,
        view={0}{90},
        point meta min=0.5,  % also
        point meta max=0.65, % important
        tick align=center,
        ytick={0.5,0.525,0.55,0.575,0.6,0.625,0.65}, % add specific ticks
        yticklabels={0.5,,0.55,,0.6,,0.65}, % do not give value to ticks
    }
    ] \addplot3[
    surf,
    point meta min=0.5,
    point meta max=0.66,
    ]
    table[header=false] {
        0.0000 0.0000 0.5038
        0.0050 0.0000 0.5538
        0.0100 0.0000 0.6034
        0.0150 0.0000 0.6066

        0.0000 0.0050 0.5135
        0.0050 0.0050 0.5635
        0.0100 0.0050 0.6132
        0.0150 0.0050 0.6159

        0.0000 0.0100 0.5233
        0.0050 0.0100 0.5733
        0.0100 0.0100 0.6231
        0.0150 0.0100 0.6253

        0.0000 0.0150 0.5243
        0.0050 0.0150 0.5745
        0.0100 0.0150 0.6243
        0.0150 0.0150 0.6262
    };
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot3[
    surf,
    point meta min=0.5,
    point meta max=0.72,
    ]
    table[header=false] {
        0.0000 0.0000 0.5138
        0.0050 0.0000 0.5738
        0.0100 0.0000 0.6334
        0.0150 0.0000 0.6666

        0.0000 0.0050 0.5135
        0.0050 0.0050 0.5835
        0.0100 0.0050 0.6332
        0.0150 0.0050 0.6459

        0.0000 0.0100 0.5433
        0.0050 0.0100 0.5933
        0.0100 0.0100 0.6431
        0.0150 0.0100 0.6653

        0.0000 0.0150 0.5543
        0.0050 0.0150 0.5745
        0.0100 0.0150 0.6443
        0.0150 0.0150 0.6762
    };
    \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 10x a lot Venez. That indeed solved most of the problem. However, I'd like to have a tick (a thin black line) between every 2 colors in the colorbar (in the middle of the fig.). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I suppose for this you should specifiy the ticks manually - see updated answer above. (which gave me the opportunity to correct 'ztick'/'zticklabels' to 'ytick'/'yticklabels')

Comment: Great, 10x a lot again.